# php array build multi-dimensional from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an

```
 array('frank','john','dan')
```

and I need to build from that an

```
array('frank'=>array('john'=>array('dan'=>array())
```

it has to be dynamic because I won't always know how many keys are in the initial array

I tried some stuff but have to admit that i'm stumped.

the problem seems to be that I can't assign a variable number of dimensions to the array, where any time I assign array keys to the largearray variable it has to be assigned to the root of the variable

```
$keys = array('base','frank','john');
foreach ($keys as $k => $key) {
    if ($k>0) {
        $largearray[$keys[$k-1]] = array($key=>array());
    }elseif ($k>1) {
        $largearray = array_push($largearray[$keys[$k-2]], array($keys[$k-1]=>array($key=>array())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this what you are looking for

```
    $arr = array('frank','john','dan');

    $finalArr = array();
    for ($x=count($arr) - 1; $x >= 0; $x--) {
        $arrElement = $arr[$x];
        $finalArr = array($arrElement => $finalArr);
    } 

    var_dump($finalArr);
```

This will result to

```
array (size=1)
  'frank' => 
    array (size=1)
      'john' => 
        array (size=1)
          'dan' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
```